# Existe um nome específico para a válvula de ar (ventil) de uma bola ou pneu?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Durante as discussões sobre uma pergunta no [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395382/which-word-begins-with-y-and-looks-like-an-axe-in-this-picture) eu queria achar o termo em inglês para aquela válvula de ar por onde se enchem bolas e pneus.

Eu sempre conheci esta peça pelo nome de *ventil* e para minha supresa ao colocá-la no [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com.br/m/translate?hl=pt-BR#pt/en/ventil) ele me perguntou se eu não queria traduzir do Alemão. Achando isto estranho resolvi procurar no [dlpo](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Ventil) e para minha maior surpresa fui informado que tal palavra não existe!

Entendo que *válvula de ar* possa ser usado, mas me parece um termo mais genérico. Existe uma palavra que seria reconhecida tanto em PT_pt quanto PT_br para designar tal peça?

Comment: A Wikipédia usa o nome [**válvula de pneu**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A1lvula_de_pneu). Seria a isso que você está se referindo?

Comment: A peça à qual me refiro é esta sim, mas este nome não deve ser utilizado para se referir à valvula de uma bola, não é?

Comment: Eu também conheço por ventil...

Comment: Em Portugal usa-se *pipo*, quer para pneus quer para bolas.

Comment: @Jacinto *Pipo* seria uma gíria ou usado de maneira mais oficial? Pergunto, pois o [DLPO](https://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/pipo) não parece indicar este uso como sendo um dos significados.

Comment: Eu acho que é informal. Em contextos mais formais, e nas embalagens de câmaras de ar, creio, vem é *válvula*. Mas vem no dicionário da Academia de Ciências de Lisboa.

Comment: No inglês, com função ligeiramente diferente, há o termo "airlock", embora uma válvula, não funciona como uma válvula de pneu, funciona mais como uma válvula para alívio de pressão. E há também o significado original do termo que são câmaras para trafegar objetos/pessoas de ambientes com pressões diferentes, exemplo entre o interior de uma espaçonave e o seu exterior.

Comment: Ventil parece ser um empréstimo linguístico válido. [Algumas línguas germânicas e eslavas](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ventil) possuem essa palavra com esse sentido, incluindo a [língua alemã](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ventil), da qual tradutor acusou ser a palavra.  Creio que não haja no português um nome para o objeto sem ser esse empréstimo linguístico ou composições como *"válvula de pneu"*, *"válvula de bola"*, *"válvula de câmara de ar"*, etc.  Talvez só o termo *"válvula"* seja válido apesar de ter sentido mais amplo do que o que deseja-se.

Comment: "Ventil" é nova pra mim. Acho que "válvula" parece ser o mais correto, embora eu sempre tenha usado o termo informal "bico" (seja para pneus, bolas, boias, ou qualquer outra coisa que se tenha uma válvula).

Comment: @Hugo por exemplo "bico da bola" ou "bico do pneu"? Essa é nova para mim!

Comment: @gmauch Exatamente. Talvez seja um termo bem regional aqui de SP (nunca reparei se em outros estados é usado, pelo jeito não...)

Comment: Normalmente chama-se pipo, embora na realidade isso seja a tampa.

Answer (score 3):

Em inglês, o nome técnico que se dá à peça que se vê na porção externa dos pneus é **valve stem** ("haste da válvula"), pois a válvula de ar propriamente dita fica situada na base dessa haste, por baixo do aro da roda. Basta buscar ["valve stem" no Google Imagens](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=valve+stem&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) que aparecerão várias hastes dessa. Um exemplo de documento em inglês que se refere à dita haste como "valve stem" é o [MAT-CSM 32-45-01](https://www.faasafety.gov/files/gslac/courses/content/269/1100/4222_12Mair_CSM_Interactive.pdf) (manual técnico da Michelin para manutenção de pneus e câmaras).

Como a válvula da bola de inflar não possui essa haste externa, em inglês a válvula de acesso é denominada simplesmente **valve** ("válvula") mesmo, como p.ex. nos mostra a [busca por "soccer ball" valve no Google Imagens](https://www.google.com.br/search?tbm=isch&sa=1&q=%22soccer%20ball%22%20valve&oq=%22soccer%20ball%22%20valve). E o orifício utilizado para se inflar a bola (ou para se inflar qualquer outro dispositivo, objeto etc.) é denominado **inlet** ("acesso", "entrada", "admissão") ou **air inlet** ("entrada de ar", "admissão de ar").

Em português, há vários nomes populares para a haste da válvula dos pneus: a [palavra alemã](https://translate.google.com.br/?client=tw-ob#de/pt/ventil) (e dinamarquesa) [**ventil** ("válvula")](https://en.langenscheidt.com/german-portuguese/ventil) eu não sabia que era usada em países lusófonos, mas ela é de origem germânica. No período (de cerca de 4 anos) em que trabalhei montando bicicletas, no estado do Espírito Santo (Brasil), muitos se referiam a essas hastes como **pistão** ou então **bico**. Mas, como citei anteriormente, tratam-se de nomes populares. E, no período em que trabalhei como mecânico de aeronaves militares (de 2003 a 2009), sempre usei o termo informal **bico** (também usado [neste website de mecânica](http://mecanicosdeplantao.com.br/site/pneus-de-aviao/), por exemplo) para me referir às hastes de acesso à válvula de ar dos pneus dos caças Northrop Grumman F-5E Tiger II e F-5M (F-5BR) nos quais eu trabalhava. Enfim: nas T.O. (*Technical Orders* / Ordens Técnicas) de aeronaves (em inglês), assim como nos demais manuais técnicos (em inglês), o que se escreve é **valve stem** mesmo. E em português há diversos nomes informais. Não existe um "padrão popular" que se possa simultaneamente aplicar ao pt-PT e pt-BR.

Em português, há vários nomes populares para essa haste, mas nos manuais técnicos o que se utiliza é a palavra genérica **válvula**, tendo em vista que na base da haste realmente há uma válvula. Uma fonte que posso usar para fundamentar minha afirmação é o [Manual de Normas Técnicas da ALAPA](http://www.strongestpneus.com.br/Manual%20ALAPA.pdf) (Associação Latino Americana de Pneus e Aros), que na página 170 apresenta a seguinte definição:

> **3.16 VÁLVULA**
>
> Componente da câmara de ar ou sistema de rodagem através do qual é possível inflar ou desinflar a câmara ou o pneu. A válvula retém o(s) fluido(s) que sustenta(m) elasticamente a carga do veículo, resiste à pressão interna e a agentes externos.

Portanto, enquanto no uso informal da língua portuguesa não existe uma palavra padrão para ser utilizada como sinônimo de **valve stem**, na literatura técnica em língua portuguesa o que se utiliza é a palavra genérica **válvula**.

PS: conforme indicado no mesmo manual da ALAPA (pág. 291), em português a tal da "haste" é denominada **extensão**.